# Python: how to instantiate new data structure based on if conditionals

Tags: python, data-structures

`n` = total number of user inputs, in the form of 2 integers: `x y`
`x y` = space separated integer input

**Problem:**
As I iterate through `n` inputs, I want to place each input into a different set, based on conditions such as if either `x` or `y` already exist in the set, add to it. Otherwise, create a new set.

**Example input:**

```
n = 4
1 2 
10 11
4 5
3 1
```

**Example output:**

```
(1,2,3)
(4,5)
(10,11)
```

**This is what I have:**

```
t = set()
x,y = raw_input()
x,y = (int(x),int(y))
t.update([x,y])

for i in xrange(1,n):
    new_set = set()
    x,y = raw_input()
    x,y = (int(x),int(y))
    if x in t or y in t:
        t.update([x,y])
    elif x not in t and y not in t:
        new_set.update([x,y])
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, because new_set is defined within the `for_loop`, and each time a new pair of `x y` is seen, `new_set` is reset.

**Question:**
How do I create new sets given that their creation is dependent on the `if-else` conditional, and there is no way to predetermine the total number of sets needed especially if `n` becomes larger?

Comment: Additional complication: if the next input was `10 3` you would have to merge two existing sets?

Comment: If next input is 10 3, I would merge the two existing sets

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, as I am on my tablet. Nonetheless,

```
# Python 3
# Should work equally well for Python 2.6+ by just replacing input with raw_input

def make_getter(type_):
    def get_type(prompt=""):
        while True:
            try:
                return type_(input(prompt))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return get_type

get_int  = make_getter(int)
get_ints = make_getter(lambda s: [int(i) for i in s.split()])

def find_group(all_groups, n):
    for group in all_groups:
        if n in group:
            return group
    return None

def main():
    all_groups = set()     # set of frozenset of int
    num_inputs = get_int("How many input pairs? ")
    for _ in range(num_inputs):
        x, y = get_ints()
        x_group = find_group(all_groups, x)
        y_group = find_group(all_groups, y)
        if x_group is None and y_group is None:
            # create new group
            all_groups.add(frozenset([x, y]))
        elif x_group is None:
            # add x to existing y group
            all_groups.remove(y_group)
            all_groups.add(y_group | {x})
        elif y_group is None:
            # add y to existing x group
            all_groups.remove(x_group)
            all_groups.add(x_group | {y})
        elif x_group is y_group:
            #special case - x and y already belong to the same group
            pass
        else:
            # merge existing x group and y group
            all_groups.remove(x_group)
            all_groups.remove(y_group)
            all_groups.add(x_group | y_group)
    # show final result
    print(all_groups)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. One part I'm unclear about: why is make_getter function needed?

Comment: When requiring type-checked input, you could just write `get_int` and `get_ints` as independent functions, but almost 100% of the code would be identical... as would `get_float`, `get_floats`, `get_words`, etc. Rather than rewrite the same thing over and over, I have a generic function creator which takes the desired type as a parameter. It's design overkill for this problem, but I'm used to doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a list of your sets, like so:

Python 3:

```
setList = []
n = 3

for i in range(n):
    x, y = input().split()
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    for s in setList:
        if x in s or y in s:
            s.update({x,y})
            break
    else:
        setList.append({x,y})
```

Python 2:

```
setList = []
n = 3

for i in xrange(n):
    x, y = raw_input().split()
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    for s in setList:
        if x in s or y in s:
            s.update({x,y})
            break
    else:
        setList.append({x,y})
```

As Hugh Bothwell pointed out in their comment on your question, this solution could run into issues when a pair in which each number belongs to a different set is inputted.